# What is wrong with the styling in these lists (HTML)

Tags: html, css, styles, styling

I've been doing the web course on Codecademy and I'm stuck on the "Styling the font!" task. 
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
<li style= "font-family: Garamond; size:16px">This item is big Garamond.</li>

<li style= "font-family: Bodoni; size:12px;" >This item is medium Bodoni.</li>

<li style= "font-family: Futura; size:10px">This item is small Futura</li>
```

Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Remember that most computers only have a limited amount of fonts installed: http://web.mit.edu/jmorzins/www/fonts.html

Answer (score 3):

Remember that most computers only have a limited amount of fonts installed: http://web.mit.edu/jmorzins/www/fonts.html

It's best practice to specify fall-back fonts too incase the users computer doesn't have the first font specified e.g.

```
font-family: arial, helvetica, georgia, verdana, sans-serif;
```

So if the computer doesn't have arial installed it will go down the list until it finds one it does have installed and it will display that.

Also you've declared size wrongly. It should be...

```
font-size: xxx;
```

Comment: Best answer here, but the font-family list should finish with a [Generic Font Family](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#generic-font-families) name.

Comment: @Alohci -  I've edited my answer to take your point into account.

Answer (score 1):

"size" should be "font-size".

`<li style= "font-family: Garamond; font-size:16px">This item is big Garamond.</li>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<li style= "font-family: Garamond; font-size:16px;">This item is big Garamond.</li>

<li style= "font-family: Bodoni; font-size:12px;" >This item is medium Bodoni.</li>

<li style= "font-family: Futura; font-size:10px;">This item is small Futura</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<li style = "font-size: 16px; font-family:Garamond">This item is big Garamond.</li>
<li style = "font-size: 12px; font-family:Bodoni">This item is medium Bodoni.</li>
<li style = "font-size: 10px; font-family:Futura">This item is small Futura.</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Defining font-family properties?**

you could use multiple fonts like this `font-family: arial, verdana, "Cooper Black";`

**Defining font size?**

define like this `font-size: 16px;`

Alternatively you could define these font properties simultaneously like this `font: 16px arial, verdan, "Cooper Black";` or `font: 16px arial;` or `font: 16px/20px arial;` below is line-height.